# Unintended stuttering when moving camera

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, glfw

I am using opengl and GLFW to make a rendering engine.

Things work per se, but there is some weird flickering happening when I move the camera.

Due the nature of the problem I need to link a youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhFrXadnWbs&feature=youtu.be

If you pay attention you will see the stuttering happening as I move the camera.

I beleive this problem occurs due to how I have implemented my camera movement, which is:

GLFW key callback:

```
#define CAM_SPEED 0.2f
void static key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_W)
    {
        c.translateForward(CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_S)
    {
        c.translateForward(-CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_A)
    {
        c.translateSideways(-CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_D)
    {
        c.translateSideways(CAM_SPEED);
    }
}
```

Camera code:

```
    void inline translateForward(float speed)
    {
        glm::vec3 hForward = forward;
        hForward.y = 0;
        hForward = normalize(hForward);

        position += hForward*speed;
    }

    void inline translateSideways(float speed)
    {
        position += side*speed;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you charge the camera's rotation? Also, do you have any rate control on how often you poll for input, so you don't move faster/slower depending on the repeat rate of the key & how many key events get caught in a particular frame?

Comment: The camera rotation is updated in the cursor position callback for GLFW. I don't have any explicit rate control however,

Comment: Sounds to me like a good thing to include in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a delay in the frequency of poll calls to the GLFW key callback function.

Changing the code so that the callback function updates some global booleans

Like this:

```
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_W)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_W=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_W=false;
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_S)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_S=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_S=false;
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_A)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_A=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_A=false;
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_D)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_D=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_D=false;
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_SPACE=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_SPACE=false;
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT)
    {
        if(action==GLFW_PRESS)
            E_SHIFT=true;
        if(action==GLFW_RELEASE)
            E_SHIFT=false;
    }
```

And then making the update happen inside of the render loop as follows:

```
if(E_W)
    c.translateForward(CAM_SPEED);
if(E_S)
    c.translateForward(-CAM_SPEED);
if(E_A)
    c.translateSideways(-CAM_SPEED);
if(E_D)
    c.translateSideways(CAM_SPEED);
if(E_SHIFT)
    c.translate(vec3(0,-1,0)*CAM_SPEED);
if(E_SPACE)
    c.translate(vec3(0,1,0)*CAM_SPEED);
```

Eliminates the stuttering.

Or simply put, the update was moved from the callback function to the render function